# How can I run the same xunit.net test suite in multiple configurations?

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, teamcity, xunit.net, appveyor

I'm developing a network client library in C# that can run either in SSL or plain-text mode. Both need to be supported. I've found a few quirks when working in one mode or another that can appear unexpectedly when testing something else. I've found it very useful to run the tests in either plain-text or SSL mode to diagnose problems.

I would like to run the library in both plain-text AND SSL modes on my CI server. I can do so quite easily by starting `dotnet test` with an environment variable to describe which mode to run but this then yields duplicate test outputs to my CI software, which is currently Appveyor but will soon be TeamCity. If a unit test failed in the SSL but not in the plain-text mode, it would not be easy to tell them apart.

At the moment, I'm thinking the best way to do this would be to prefix the name of each test case reported to the CI software, with the run type, but I couldn't find a way to do that. I'm open to other suggestions however.

Other ideas I've had:

- Rewriting all tests to use `[Theory]` - this seems like a great deal of work and I wouldn't be able to set up using constructors. I also have a number of `[Theory]` tests which I'd have to figure out somehow.
- Setting up a different CI configuration for each distinct test run - this would be fine now but if I have to run the same tests against different versions of the same software, I could end up with 10 or more configurations.

In this case, neither feels like the correct way to solve the problem and I hope there's a more elegant solution as I'm sure I'm not the only one with this issue.

Answer (score -1):

With xUnit you can use traits or category to achieve this

http://www.brendanconnolly.net/organizing-tests-with-xunit-traits/

I know it can definitely be done in TeamCity